# Spring ResourceArrayPropertyEditor: How to filter only files?

Tags: spring

I am using spring.ios ResourceArrayPropertyEditor to find all resources matching certain patterns (to make it easier for this example, lets say, I am looking for foo-files):

What I do:

```
ResourceArrayPropertyEditor resolver = new ResourceArrayPropertyEditor();
String[] resourcePattern = new String[]{"classpath*:**/*.foo"};
resolver.setValue(resourcePattern);
Resource[] resources = (Resource[]) resolver.getValue();
```

Problem: this not only finds all "*.foo" files I have on my classpath, but also finds all package-folders that end with "foo", for example: "org.mydomain.database.foo".

I do not need these entries and even will get errors when trying to process them.

How can I filter the resources to only contain files? (like a `find . -type f`).

Comment: Do you really have package-folder with name `org.mydomain.database.sql`? I believe it is not valid package-folder name.

Comment: In my real case, I am looking for "*.dmn" files and there is a package org.camunda.bpm.dmn"   I just wanted to keep the specifics out of this issue.    I will chage it to foo in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation [says](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/ResourceArrayPropertyEditor.html), that `ResourceArrayPropertyEditor` is using `PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver` by default, for resolve particular resources. Judging from [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java#L679) of `PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver`, it will select all resources matched to specified pattern, and does not check is it directory or file.

The only option, is check `isReadable()` property of `Resource` after you get list of resources.

```
Resource[] resources = (Resource[]) resolver.getValue();
for(Resource resource : resources){
    if(resource.isReadable()){
        //will work only for files
    }
}
```

Or if you use Java 8 stream:

```
Resource [] resources = (Resource[]) resolver.getValue();
Resource [] fileResources = Arrays.stream(resources).filter(Resource::isReadable).toArray(Resource[]::new);
```

This method is more preferable than, `resource.getFile().isDirectory()`, because there is no need to handle an `IOException`.

Comment: Could you provide a working unit test? I gave this a try, but without success, seems like the packages are "readable", too ...

Comment: the `!resource.getFile().isDirectory()` works however

Comment: @JanGalinski I've found it in documentation. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/FileSystemResource.html. And when I tested, files was readable, but folders are not. Possible, you get from editor another implementation of `Resource`, not `FileSystemResource`.

Comment: That's it. I scanned file system. UrlResource has not implemented isReadable. Method of parents AbstractResource class will always return true. I had to think about it.